# c# web api How to pass a url as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a c# Web api, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("gatewayinfo/{endpointAddress}")]
public GatewayModel GetGatewayInfo(string endpointAddress)
```

when I call that api I need to pass in an url as address (http://example.con)

How can I do that with HttpClient? If I put url in parameter it won't work :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(token);
var result = await client.GetStringAsync(_webApiAddress + parameter);
```

Comment: So what's the value of `_webApiAddress + parameter` just before execution? Did you verify that your API returns correct data if e.g. called with `http://localhost:8080/gatewayinfo/http://www.example.com/`? These slashes in the "URL" could make it difficult to parse; seems like a weird format to me with the protocoll. Maybe just do a `gatewayinfo/example.com` without slashes in the `endpointAddress`?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the url before passing it as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to encode the `param`

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_webapiAddress);
    client.SetBearerToken(token)

    var result  = await client.GetStringAsync($"gatewayinfo/{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter)}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually made a change to Convert url to base64 and pass the base64 string as parameter. At web api I convert base64 back to url.